# decompiling an obfuscated dll - next steps?

Tags: c#, .net, obfuscation, decompiler, deobfuscation

I have successfully (or at least I think successfully) unobfuscated a dll using de4dot which indicated that it had identified the obfuscator in question. From there I've decompiled into a Visual studio project which appears to the initial view to be readable if still very obfuscated and confusing set of source code.

My initial attempt to recompile this with zero changes has met with a plethora of errors, including XAML errors, missing definitions within classes and form designer issues. Some of these I've commented out as I think they're decompiler generated useless code. Others I have no ideas how to even begin to fix.

I am way out of my depth with this, but want to try to press on but not sure exactly where to begin. The missing definitions within the classes worry me most as that suggests to me that the decompile has not worked entirely or correctly. Is this possible?

I realise I'm not giving much away here, but I'm not sure exactly what information you guys will require to steer me right.

Comment: The point of obfuscators is that it ain't easy to deobfuscate them. There's nothing we can tell you that would help and still be acceptable.

Comment: @Will Surely though the point of an obfuscator is to render the program confusing and difficult to follow for the human eye and brain. Not to render them impossible for say Visual Studio to recompile with zero changes? I'm content that the deobfuscation is going to be a PITA and extremely manual and labour intensive, but I want to know that the starting code is complete before I start.